# Rails remove '\' from json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

json response

```
 {"skill"=>"{\"dept_id\"=>\"01\", \"user_id\"=>\"001\", \"level_cd\"=>\"04_swim\", \"first_name\"=>\"rohit\", \"last_name\"=>\"patel\", \"dept_full_name\"=>\"swiming\", \"rank\"=>\"04_swim\"}, {\"dept_id\"=>\"02\", \"user_id\"=>\"002\", \"level_cd\"=>\"04_swim\", \"first_name\"=>\"ranjit\", \"last_name\"=>\"shinde\", \"dept_full_name\"=>\"running\", \"rank\"=>\"03_run\"}, {\"dept_id\"=>\"04\", \"user_id\"=>\"004\", \"level_cd\"=>\"02_jump\", \"first_name\"=>\"kedar\", \"last_name\"=>\"patil\", \"dept_full_name\"=>\"jumping\", \"rank\"=>\"02_jump\"}, {\"dept_id\"=>\"05\", \"user_id\"=>\"005\", \"level_cd\"=>\"03_run\", \"first_name\"=>\"kapil\", \"last_name\"=>\"bote\", \"dept_full_name\"=>\"Hammer\", \"rank\"=>\"03_run\"}"
```

How to remove only \ from this response

expected output is

```
    "skill"=>{"dept_id"=>"01", "user_id"=>"001", "level_cd"=>"04_swim", "first_name"=>"rohit", "last_name"=>"patel", "dept_full_name"=>"swiming", "rank"=>"04_swim"}, {"dept_id"=>"02", "user_id"=>"002", "level_cd"=>"04_swim", "first_name"=>"ranjit", "last_name"=>"shinde", "dept_full_name"=>"running", "rank"=>"03_run"}, {"dept_id"=>"04", "user_id"=>"004", "level_cd"=>"02_jump", "first_name"=>"kedar", "last_name"=>"patil", "dept_full_name"=>"jumping", "rank"=>"02_jump"}, {"dept_id"=>"05", "user_id"=>"005", "level_cd"=>"03_run", "first_name"=>"kapil", "last_name"=>"bote", "dept_full_name"=>"Hammer", "rank"=>"03_run"}
```

Comment: Sorry abou this, i have put expected output. Please check it.

Comment: puts `json_string` will convert the data for you

Comment: That string is not valid JSON. It is just a _partial_ string representation of a Ruby array of hashes. Without context how you generated that string nobody will be able to help you because the next string could be invalid for other reasons. How do build that string? Where is it coming from? I suggest fixing the JSON generation first.

Comment: It's not working for my params.

Comment: This is not JSON. Your problem is not "how to remove the backslashes from the JSON response". Your problem is that you do not have JSON there at all. *That* is what you need to fix.

Comment: Yes, aggree with @JörgWMittag, but either i need to remove backslash or take proper response json from view, i have tried to take response with converting object to_json, but it's not proper response like:  `{"skill"=>{"0"=>{"dept_id"=>"01", "user_id"=>"001", "level_cd"=>"04_swim", "first_name"=>"rohit", "last_name"=>"patel", "dept_full_name"=>"swiming", "rank"=>"04_swim"}`  it's giving with index value.

Comment: What you have there *is not JSON*. Period. If it's not JSON, then there is *absolutely no point in trying to fix it*. You need to figure out why the thing that you think is JSON is not.

Comment: Also, there *are no backslashes*. Those are printed by `String#inspect`, but they are *not* actually in the string. They are purely for human readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently no backslashes in the string. The backslash is only there because the context is within a double quoted string context.

If you want to use a double quote in double quoted string context you need to escape it with a backslash, otherwise the compiler thinks you want to end the string.

```
"John Doe said: "Hello Word!""
```

The above is not valid. The `"` before `Hello World!` will end the string. Meaning that `Hello World!` will not be in string context and Ruby tries to parse `Hello` and `World` as constants.

To prevent this from happening you escape the `"` with a backslash `\`.

```
"John Doe said: \"Hello Word!\""
```

`\"` will be interpreted as one `"` character. There is no backslash present within the resulting string. See the [Ruby literals](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings) documentation.

When using single quotes for string delimiters there is no need to escape the double quotes (but you do need to escape single quotes). The above could also be written as:

```
'John Doe said: "Hello Word!"'
```

Similarly your data can be written as:

```
{"skill"=>'{"dept_id"=>"01", "user_id"=>"001", "level_cd"=>"04_swim", "first_name"=>"rohit", "last_name"=>"patel", "dept_full_name"=>"swiming", "rank"=>"04_swim"}, {"dept_id"=>"02", "user_id"=>"002", "level_cd"=>"04_swim", "first_name"=>"ranjit", "last_name"=>"shinde", "dept_full_name"=>"running", "rank"=>"03_run"}, {"dept_id"=>"04", "user_id"=>"004", "level_cd"=>"02_jump", "first_name"=>"kedar", "last_name"=>"patil", "dept_full_name"=>"jumping", "rank"=>"02_jump"}, {"dept_id"=>"05", "user_id"=>"005", "level_cd"=>"03_run", "first_name"=>"kapil", "last_name"=>"bote", "dept_full_name"=>"Hammer", "rank"=>"03_run"}'
```

The above clearly demonstrates that there are no backslash characters present in the string.

However the string is not JSON. I suggest changing the server response if possible. You can `eval` the current response, but I would advise not to use `eval` ever (`eval` is evil). If the server would send malicious Ruby code, `eval` will execute it without any issues and might corrupt your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the hash example needs to end with an `}` to be valid. So I added it in my example. Further more it looks to be a collection of records, but it also looks like it's missing a list. If it were inside a list it would be valid but as the example stands now, it is not a valid hash.

But let's say just for fun, I did want to take the string and put it inside an array. Maybe something like this:

```
 data = {"skill"=>"{\"dept_id\"=>\"01\", \"user_id\"=>\"001\", \"level_cd\"=>\"04_swim\", \"first_name\"=>\"rohit\", \"last_name\"=>\"patel\", \"dept_full_name\"=>\"swiming\", \"rank\"=>\"04_swim\"}, {\"dept_id\"=>\"02\", \"user_id\"=>\"002\", \"level_cd\"=>\"04_swim\", \"first_name\"=>\"ranjit\", \"last_name\"=>\"shinde\", \"dept_full_name\"=>\"running\", \"rank\"=>\"03_run\"}, {\"dept_id\"=>\"04\", \"user_id\"=>\"004\", \"level_cd\"=>\"02_jump\", \"first_name\"=>\"kedar\", \"last_name\"=>\"patil\", \"dept_full_name\"=>\"jumping\", \"rank\"=>\"02_jump\"}, {\"dept_id\"=>\"05\", \"user_id\"=>\"005\", \"level_cd\"=>\"03_run\", \"first_name\"=>\"kapil\", \"last_name\"=>\"bote\", \"dept_full_name\"=>\"Hammer\", \"rank\"=>\"03_run\"}"}

parsed_data = data["skill"].split("}, ").map{|x| x.end_with?("\"") ? x + '}' : x}.map{|x| eval(x)}

puts parsed_data



{"dept_id"=>"01", "user_id"=>"001", "level_cd"=>"04_swim", "first_name"=>"rohit", "last_name"=>"patel", "dept_full_name"=>"swiming", "rank"=>"04_swim"}
{"dept_id"=>"02", "user_id"=>"002", "level_cd"=>"04_swim", "first_name"=>"ranjit", "last_name"=>"shinde", "dept_full_name"=>"running", "rank"=>"03_run"}
{"dept_id"=>"04", "user_id"=>"004", "level_cd"=>"02_jump", "first_name"=>"kedar", "last_name"=>"patil", "dept_full_name"=>"jumping", "rank"=>"02_jump"}
{"dept_id"=>"05", "user_id"=>"005", "level_cd"=>"03_run", "first_name"=>"kapil", "last_name"=>"bote", "dept_full_name"=>"Hammer", "rank"=>"03_run"}
```

Now with the data in an array you can convert it to json if you'd like

```
require 'json'
2.6.5 :007 > parsed_data.to_json
 => "[{\"dept_id\":\"01\",\"user_id\":\"001\",\"level_cd\":\"04_swim\",\"first_name\":\"rohit\",\"last_name\":\"patel\",\"dept_full_name\":\"swiming\",\"rank\":\"04_swim\"},{\"dept_id\":\"02\",\"user_id\":\"002\",\"level_cd\":\"04_swim\",\"first_name\":\"ranjit\",\"last_name\":\"shinde\",\"dept_full_name\":\"running\",\"rank\":\"03_run\"},{\"dept_id\":\"04\",\"user_id\":\"004\",\"level_cd\":\"02_jump\",\"first_name\":\"kedar\",\"last_name\":\"patil\",\"dept_full_name\":\"jumping\",\"rank\":\"02_jump\"},{\"dept_id\":\"05\",\"user_id\":\"005\",\"level_cd\":\"03_run\",\"first_name\":\"kapil\",\"last_name\":\"bote\",\"dept_full_name\":\"Hammer\",\"rank\":\"03_run\
```

Comment: And yes, eval is super dangerous